# Проблема с кодировкой при вставке записей в БД

Tags: веб-программирование, php, mysql

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане. При попытке вставить запись с русскими символами, бьется кодировка.
Вот сведения о таблице

```
 (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `xml_id` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `inn` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `kpp` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `register_addr` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `actual_addr` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `work_phone` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=220 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Вот код, с помощью которого выполняется запись

```
$dbLink = mysql_connect($DBHost, $DBLogin, $DBPassword);//Знаю, что рекомендуют использовать PDO, но этой возможности сейчас нет.
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$dbLink);
mysql_select_db($DBName, $dbLink);
mysql_query('INSERT INTO test (name) values (\'юююю\')', $dbLink);
```

Файл в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM.
Пробовал деталь так:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $dbLink); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $dbLink );
```

Не помогло.

```
mysql_client_encoding();//Возвращает utf8
```

Если выполнить такой запрос

```
SELECT CHARSET(name) from test;
```

Получаю значение utf8

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.
Заранее спасибо.

**Обновление**

Факт битой кодировки определяю путем запроса SELECT ... в консоли. С СУБД соединяюсь с помощью putty. В настройках кодировки соединения стоит utf8, но я вижу крякозябы. На самой html странице все нормально смотрится.

Вот, на всякий случай, кусочек конфига `my.cnf`

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

Еще один момент. По непонятным причинам я не могу установить COLLATE в значение
utf8_general_ci
Пишу следующий запрос

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY name varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL
```

В итоге получаю следующий результат
name varchar(150) и все. Ни CHARACTER SET ни COLLATE

Answer (score 2):

как я понял, проблема в том, что при подключении из *ms/windows* с помощью программы `putty` по протоколу `ssh` и выполнении *sql-запроса* в оболочке `mysql`, выводимые символы выглядят «как-то неправильно».

«виновных» может быть несколько: сама база данных, сервер базы данны, клиент базы данных, консоль сервера, `putty`, *ms/windows*.

чтобы рассечь этот «гордиев узел» примерно пополам (на пункте «консоль сервера»), выполните, подключившись к серверу обычным путём, такую команду:

```
$ echo -e '\xd1\x8e'
```

если будет выведена русская буква `ю`, значит, проблема «слева» от пункта «консоль сервера».

если же увидите «что-то неправильное», то попробуйте так (*):

```
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
$ echo -e '\xd1\x8e'
```

если увидите букву `ю`, то проблема локализована: добавьте первую из строк в конец файла `~/.bashrc` (я предполагаю, что в качестве оболочки на сервере используется именно *gnu/bash*).

если же опять увидите «что-то неправильное», то проверьте, сгенерирована ли локаль `en_US.UTF-8` (в выводе она может называться и `en_US.utf8` — это допустимо):

```
$ locale -a | grep en_US
```

если локали такой нет — сгенерируйте её:

```
$ echo 'en_US.UTF-8' | sudo tee -a /etc/locale.gen
$ sudo locale-gen
```

после генерации локали имеет смысл перелогиниться.

если упомянутая локаль в системе присутствует, а две команды (после `попробуйте так (*)`) всё равно возвращают «что-то непонятное», то проблема «справа» от пункта «консоль сервера».

---

то, что «слева» от пункта «консоль сервера», я разбирать уже не буду, т.к. с огромной вероятностью проблема к этому моменту уже локализована.

Answer (score 0):

Бьюсь об заклад, что факт неправильной кодировки вы определяете скриптом, который в конце делает что-то типа echo

если так, то браузер скорее всего воспринимает выведенную информацию в кодировке cp1251 и соответственно вы видите крякозябры, но стоит поменять кодировку страницы в браузере или отдавать заголовки, указывающие что это utf8 и все станет нормально

Comment: @jenikok А почему Вы не представили примеры, как это сделать? Много воды

Comment: Факт не правильности кодировки определяю путем запроса SELECT ... в консоли. С СУБД соединяюсь с помощью putty. В настройках кодировки соединения стоит utf8, но я вижу крякозябы. На самой html странице все нормально смотрится.
Вот, на всякий случай, кусочек конфига my.cnf
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8

Answer (score 0):

а причем здесь "много воды"?
Если браузер возвращает нормальную кодировку - значит все нормально настроено.
Если весь сырбор из-за того, что в putty выводится что угодно кроме русского - то это другой вопрос. Проверяйте настройки самого putty (change settings -> Window -> Translation -> должна стоять UTF-8)

Comment: @лумшт 

> а причем здесь "много воды"?

Сравните ответ @jenikok и ответ, который я [давал ранее](http://hashcode.ru/questions/386724#386787).

Так или иначе, здесь проблема иного характера.

Comment: В том то и дело, что в change settings -> Window -> Translation -> стоит UTF-8 :)

Comment: @Nicholas Essen: Локаль на сервере какая? То-есть что вернет команда locale выполненная в консоли? В какой кодировке по-умолчанию веб-сервер отдает файлы? Определен-ли AddDefaultCharset и какое там значение?

Answer (score 0):

Прямо в БД mysql в разделе "операции" есть строка "сравнение". Установите там "utf-8 general ci"