# комментарии в консоли SSH на русском некорректны

Tags: debian, ssh, консоль

Зашел в консоль по SSH на виртуалку; установил: composer, git, phpunit
И не смог сделать первый commit -m '' - не дает печатать русскими буквами консоль ведет себя непредсказуемо. Для наглядности зашел в первый попавшийся текстовый файл через mc и напечатал там все буквы русского алфавита(не по алфавиту) - вид ужасный

Debian 8 
терминал /bin/bash

Как сделать поддержку русских букв?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для соединения использую PuTTY

Comment: начните с установки utf-8 в качестве кодировки при подключении в вашем ssh-клиенте, а дальше: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436978/178576

Comment: echo -e '\xd1\x8e' - корректно выводит ю. @alexander barakin но куда копать дальше? я новичок в консоле linux

Comment: а я (почти) полный профан в операционной системе *ms/windows* (много лет её вообще в глаза не видел), где и закопан корень вашей проблемы (а не в «консоли», с которой вы вообще не здесь не сталкиваетесь, и не в программе linux). вот придут пользователи *ms/windows* — что-нибудь более дельное подскажут.

Comment: @Mcile: Поставьте вашему консольному окну юникодный шрифт для начала. Если он есть, проблема на стороне putty или дальше.

Comment: Поставил @ VladD - помогло

Comment: ro_RO — это, внезапно, румынская локаль. Romania.
А российская, внезапно — ru_RU. Russia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Закачиваем пакет лоаклизаций

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

2 Выбираем `ru_RU.UTF-8`

3 Запускаем команду перенастройки

```
$ sudo aptitude install console-cyrillic


What virtual consoles do you use?                           -->  /dev/tty[1-6]
Choose the keyboard layout                                  -->  Russian
Toggling between Cyrillic and Latin characters              -->  Caps Lock
Switching temporarily between Cyrillic and Latin characters -->  No temporary switch
Choose a font for the console.                              -->  UniCyr
What is your favourite font size?                           -->  14
What is your encoding?                                      -->  UNICODE
Do you want to setup Cyrillic on the console at boot-time?  -->  Yes
```

4 Запуск

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/console-cyrillic start
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если напортачили и сбился язык mc например( --help команды по прежнему на английском), то поможет команда

```
$ export LANG=en_US.utf8; mc
```